# lsblk: Why FSSIZE is not equal to FSAVAIL + FSUSED

Tags: filesystems, size, lsblk

```
sudo lsblk --fs -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,FSSIZE,FSUSED,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINTS,LABEL,PATH | grep -v '^loop'

NAME                    FSTYPE       SIZE FSSIZE FSUSED FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS    LABEL          PATH
zram0                                  8G                              [SWAP]                        /dev/zram0
nvme0n1                              1.8T                                                            /dev/nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1             ext4         768M                                                            /dev/nvme0n1p1
├─nvme0n1p2             ext4         768M 738.4M 240.9M  443.8M    33% /boot          FedoraBoot     /dev/nvme0n1p2
├─nvme0n1p3             ext4         768M                                             UnassignedBoot /dev/nvme0n1p3
├─nvme0n1p4             vfat         128M 127.7M  22.4M  105.3M    18% /boot/efi      EFI-SP         /dev/nvme0n1p4
└─nvme0n1p5             LVM2_member  1.8T                                                            /dev/nvme0n1p5
  ├─vgubuntu-FedoraRoot ext4         100G  98.1G  47.9G   45.2G    49% /              FedoraRoot     /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-FedoraRoot
  ├─vgubuntu-FedoraSwap swap          32G                              [SWAP]                        /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-FedoraSwap
  ├─vgubuntu-UbuntuSwap swap          32G                                                            /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-UbuntuSwap
  ├─vgubuntu-UbuntuRoot ext4          50G                                                            /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-UbuntuRoot
  ├─vgubuntu-UbuntuHome ext4          18G                                                            /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-UbuntuHome
  ├─vgubuntu-FedoraHome ext4          18G  17.5G   6.5G   10.1G    37% /home          FedoraHome     /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-FedoraHome
  ├─vgubuntu-Data       ext4         100G  98.1G    82G   11.6G    84% /mnt/Data      Data           /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Data
  ├─vgubuntu-Documents  ext4         250G   245G 208.5G     24G    85% /mnt/Documents Documents      /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Documents
  ├─vgubuntu-Media      ext4         500G 491.1G 331.2G  134.8G    67% /mnt/Media     Media          /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Media
  └─vgubuntu-Backup     ext4         100G  97.9G   9.1G   83.7G     9% /mnt/Backup    Backup         /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Backup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ext4 by default reserves 5% of the filesystem for root-only use. This reserved space isn't counted in `FSUSED`.

For example, if we create a 10G filesystem:

```
truncate -s10g disk.img
loopdev=$(losetup -fP --show disk.img)
mkfs.ext4 $loopdev
mount $loopdev /mnt
```

...and then run your `lsblk` command:

```
lsblk --fs -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,FSSIZE,FSUSED,FSAVAIL,FSUSE%,MOUNTPOINTS,LABEL,PATH | grep loop
```

We see:

```
NAME        FSTYPE    SIZE FSSIZE FSUSED FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS                         LABEL                 PATH
loop0       ext4       10G   9.7G    24K    9.2G     0% /mnt                                                      /dev/loop0
```

Here we see that `FSUSED` (0) + `FSAVAIL` (9.2G) is exactly 5% less than `FSSIZE` (9.7G):

```
>>> 9.7 - (9.7 * 0.05)
9.215
```

You can see these reserved blocks by running `dumpe2fs`:

```
# dumpe2fs /dev/loop0 | grep -i 'block count'
dumpe2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021)
Block count:              2621440
Reserved block count:     131072
```

---

We can modify the amount of reserved space with the `-m` argument to `mkfs.ext4`. If instead we had run:

```
mkfs.ext4 -m0 $loopdev
```

We would see:

```
NAME        FSTYPE    SIZE FSSIZE FSUSED FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS                         LABEL                 PATH
loop0       ext4       10G   9.7G    24K    9.7G     0% /mnt                                                      /dev/loop0
```

We can *change* the amount of reserved space on an existing filesystem [using the tune2fs command](https://ma.ttias.be/change-reserved-blocks-ext3-ext4-filesystem-linux/).